# My Linux server is thought to be under a DDOS attack and no access to SSH - what to do?

Tags: linux, ddos

How can I fix the issues from a DDOS attack without any SSH access at all.

My main domain is http://www.reddexservers.co.uk - is there any way of checking if it is under attack externally?

Thanks!

Comment: i can connect fine, pretty quickly, sounds more like you locked yourself out... flagging though

Comment: how did I lock myself out? Didn't do anything 0_0

Comment: Would the downvoter on this question please add a comment explaining why they downvoted the user, and offer a friendly suggestion to the user as to how they can increase the quality of the call for help?

Comment: @arrocharGeek Here you go: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555375/en-us

Comment: Use whatever out of band management option you have: console port, DRAC, iLO, LOM, dialup, etc. If you don't have out of band management, well, that sucks then. Do you have a MRTG box or anything of the sort that can monitor the network devices in front of/behind your server? They would be the best indicator of a DDOS.

Comment: We use a datacentre as hosts so I personally don't have access to any of these devices :(

Comment: Get them on the phone then, because if you're getting hit by a DDOS its probably affecting more of their customers. They'll want to know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your site (HTTP) seems fine from here, though SSH access appears to blocked ("connection refused", so either a firewall or the SSH daemon is not running).
2. You are ***ALMOST CERTAINLY*** not being DDoS'd: In the 2 hours your question has been up your ISP would have probably noticed the attack, tracked you down as the target and called you to scream in your ear about the amount of traffic hitting their network.
   Also any DDoS worth its salt would have probably knocked your website down too.
3. Just because something is not working ***does NOT*** mean you are being "DDoS'd". Jumping to this conclusion is entirely to common on ServerFault (search for "DDoS" to see how many times this same speech has been given).
   The more mundane answer (a misconfigured firewall, accidentally locking yourself out with failed password attempts, the SSH daemon being killed somehow) is almost always correct.
4. If you do not have any out of band management / remote console functionality you should contact your provider and ask them to investigate the problem.